# Magento Paypal Express Button Not Showing

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.5

I am running Magento 1.5.1 and recently launched a new website. Currently I am accepting payments via Paypal Payments PRO, and have setup the Paypal API Signature. I also enabled the Paypal Express payment method, and included my Paypal email address in the configuration. For some reason, the Paypal payment option is not showing on the cart or checkout page. My currency is set to USD, and my template is configured to show all payment methods. I also have Paypal express enabled on my paypal account. When I add an item to the cart, and navigation to http://www.mydomain.com/paypal/express/start/ I get forwarded to paypal with all of the proper information.

Any ideas why the button is not showing? I have spent the past 4 hours trying to find a solution, searched all over the web, and still have not been able to determine the solution.

Comment: Change your Configuration Scope to make sure it is enabled for your store view.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I confirmed that it is enabled in my store view.

Answer (score 2):

Does the PayPal logo appear on the final checkout page or not at all?

If only on the final checkout page take a look at your Express Checkout configuration. There should be a setting called "shortcut on shopping cart" which needs to be set to yes.

To check this do the following:

- Log into Magento Admin
- Hover over "System" Click "Configuration"
- On the next page in the left menu under "SALES" click "PayPal"
- Under the "Express Checkout Settings" Section ensure "shortcut on shopping cart" is set to yes.

If PayPal doesn't appear at all, this is typically due to a template issue. To test this, try updating the cart to the default template then check to see if PayPal appears.